# When using Mono Touch can I also package for a standard Window application?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, xamarin.ios, cross-platform

I know that Mono Touch enables developing with nearly one source code and deploy to Android, iOs and Windows Mobile. There will of course be 3 projects and some platform related code but I will have important common code in C#.

But I also need my development to work on standard Windows 7 and 8 (non mobile).
Can I do this with Mono Touch and I yes what is the development process ?

Comment: It has as my dev should be used across ios, android, wp and regular windows for desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should check out my answer to this question: [Consuming ViewModels in MonoDroid / MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133270/consuming-viewmodels-in-monodroid-monotouch)

In general, you should create a shared class library that will be used on all platforms.

This class library would then be consumed by as many UIs as you need, such as MonoTouch, Mono for Android, WP7, Windows, Metro, etc.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer, did you test this approach with windows, ios and android ? Or is it theoritical ? Reading your comment it seems rather a good solution but i would like some concrete feedback

Comment: I originally wrote that post for a B2B (enterprise) app we were working on.  But we also took this approach with this app, iOS version: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/picturethis-free/id517704984?ls=1&mt=8 Android Version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hitcents.picturethis WP7 would be a quick port, but we decided there was not enough money in it.  You might have seen this app on Xamarin's home page.